# How to use StreamBridge to send String message and bypass message conversion?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

#### Background

Consider this sample code:

```java
streamBridge.send("supply-out-0", (Object) "[hello world]", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
```

With the above code, I am sending a very simple plain text `String` object data to a stream binding.

**Notice the square brackets (i.e. `[`, `]`) that are added intentionally into the message content.**

---

#### Problem

Because of the square brackets, this fails with below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to convert. Possible bug as the conversion probably shouldn't have been attampted here
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.json.JacksonMapper.doFromJson(JacksonMapper.java:70)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.json.JsonMapper.fromJson(JsonMapper.java:94)
```

It also gives the same error even with below binding-level `content-type` config:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        supply-out-0:
          destination: xxx
          binder: xxx
          content-type: text/plain
# ... omitted ...
```

---

#### Question and my thought

I feel like this is a bug, will probably report it later in their GitHub.

**Right now I need a way to fix it (the implementation code, not my message content). Does anyone know how?**

What I know so far is, this binding, `supply-out-0`, gets its name by concatenating the function name of the supplier and `-out-` and the index (always `0` for single output).

That function gets called every second, but no way I can call it manually (e.g. from an HTTP request endpoint call) and provide an input message as it accepts no argument.

```java
@Bean
public Supplier<String> supply() {
    return () -> "Hello World";
}
```

So, I feel like `StreamBridge` is the only way to manually trigger Spring Cloud Stream to send a message to my messaging topic. But unfortunately, it does not work as expected.

---

#### Dependency versions

| Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- |
| `spring-cloud-dependencies` | `2021.0.3` |
| `spring-boot-dependencies` | `2.7.1` |
| `spring-cloud-stream` | Tried both `3.2.4` (managed) and `3.2.6` (override) |

---

#### Others

Note: The type casting above is required to resolve compilation error coming from `ambiguous` method call .

- `StreamBridge#send(String, Object, MimeType)`
- `StreamBridge#send(String, String, Object)`

Comment: Yes, `StreamBridge` is the right way to send arbitrary output. Try setting the output binding contentType to `text/plain`.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for your comment but I already mentioned above that I already tried... But it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in spring-cloud-function to me.

It is incorrectly assuming that the payload is a json collection because it "looks" like one...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to convert. Possible bug as the conversion probably shouldn't have been attampted here
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.json.JacksonMapper.doFromJson(JacksonMapper.java:70) ~[spring-cloud-function-context-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.json.JsonMapper.fromJson(JsonMapper.java:94) ~[spring-cloud-function-context-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.fluxifyInputIfNecessary(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:829) ~[spring-cloud-function-context-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
```

```java
if (JsonMapper.isJsonStringRepresentsCollection(payload)
        && !FunctionTypeUtils.isTypeCollection(this.inputType) && !FunctionTypeUtils.isTypeArray(this.inputType)) {
    MessageHeaders headers = ((Message) input).getHeaders();
    Collection collectionPayload = jsonMapper.fromJson(payload, Collection.class);
```

```
JsonMapper.isJsonStringRepresentsCollection(payload)
```

returns true. I suggest you raise an issue against that project.